# How do I start RMAN over with a DB that has the same name as an older DB?

Tags: rman

in RMAN, i unregister the DB and all iterations of it disappear, but then I re-register and it all comes back.  This is a clone restore of a production DB to a dev DB that used to exist but has "keep forever" backups.  When I register this "new" DB, it has the same DBID and KEY as the old one.  Is there an easy way to get it to quit looking to archive a "file" from before the clone was done?  It's looking for a file #536 when i am like in the 1700s!.... help!

Comment: Is this with Oracle? Which version?

Answer (score -2):

Please change the DBID using the below link and re-register again.

[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch14.htm#:~:text=To%20change%20the%20DBID%20of%20a%20database%2C%20the%20database%20must,option%20after%20changing%20the%20DBID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch14.htm#:%7E:text=To%20change%20the%20DBID%20of%20a%20database%2C%20the%20database%20must,option%20after%20changing%20the%20DBID).

Comment: You should post the salient points from your link as part of your answer, lest it becomes useless when the link goes stale.